# How do I enlarge the pie chart and shift to the center

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with highcharts.js and I have two questions related to making my pie charts:

How do I enlarge each of these pie charts and how do I set the two chart in the middle of the pane?

```
$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container', type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Pesticide Residues On Domestic and Imported Foods'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Percent of foods that exceed FDA or EPA tolerances',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: { enabled: false }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Domestic foods',
            size: 150,
            x: 0,
            center: [100, 100],
            data: [
                ['Firefox', 44.2], ['IE7', 26.6], ['IE6', 20], ['Chrome', 3.1], ['Other', 5.4]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Imported foods',
            size: 150,
            center: [300, 100],
            data: [
                ['Firefox', 44.2], ['IE7', 26.6], ['IE6', 20], ['Chrome', 3.1], ['Other', 5.4]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc2n1L7v/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this works for you?

widened a little bit the container and increased size on JS.

in HTML

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 550px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></div>
```

in JS

```
//...
size: 200,
// ....
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc2n1L7v/8/)

Answer (score 1):

See the updated [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sc2n1L7v/7/)

I removed the style from the container and added this to a CSS

```
#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

(added the red border for illustration purposes only, you can remove it)

Also, each series has a `size` attribute.  You can change the value to any number of your liking.  I changed one to 250 - i.e.:

`size: 250,`